# Java generate code byte 256*256 & 0xff

Tags: java, random, hex

I need to generate a 3-bytes code (like A502F1). I am given a criteria:

> 1st byte is (serialCodeNumber / (256*256) ) & 0xFF
>
> 2nd is (serialCodeNumber / 256) & 0xFF
>
> 3th is (serialCodeNumber) & 0xFF
>
> *serialCodeNumber is a sequence 1-0xFFF*

What does that mean!?

I would generate it like this:

```
String codeNum = new BigInteger(256, random).toString(16).toUpperCase().substring(0, 6);
```

But what is the right way of doing it as the requirement says?

Comment: lookup java hexadecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what is meant by the `serialCodeNumber`, since if it is later on divided by 65025 it has to be a considerably larger number than 0xFFF (which is 4095) for it to make any reasonable sense.

But let's take a look at the conditions, they would all make sense once you are accustomed to the bitwise AND operator. A good read is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256644/how-does-the-bitwise-and-work-in-java) on how it works but the meat of the matter from that question in my opinion is this sentence by [Markus Jarderot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256644/how-does-the-bitwise-and-work-in-java):

> The result is the bits that are turned on in both numbers.

Since in your conditions you have `& 0xFF` and 0xFF is 255, or in binary it's 11111111 the first eight bits that are all turned on. This is a neat trick to just retrieve only the first 8 bits of any number. And as we all know 8 bits make up a byte. (Are you starting to see where this all is coming together now?)

As for the conditions before the `& 0xFF`, some might recognize them as bit shift operations hidden behind divisions.

`(serialCodeNumber / (256*256))` is equivalent to `(serialCodeNumber >> 16)`

and

`(serialCodeNumber / 256)` is equivalent to `(serialCodeNumber >> 8)`

But that is not that important in this case.

So the first condition takes the `serialCodeNumber` divides it by 65025 (256*256) and then looks at the 8 right most bits and ignores any other, from those 8 bits it constructs a byte.

In Java you can pretty much just write the condition as it is:

```
byte myFirstByte = (byte) ((serialCodeNumber / (256*256)) & 0xFF);
```

The other conditions aren't much different:

```
byte mySecondByte = (byte) ((serialCodeNumber / (256)) & 0xFF);
```

and

```
byte myThirdByte = (byte) ((serialCodeNumber) & 0xFF);
```

Once you have all three of your bytes, I'm assuming you need to convert them to a hex String. So I'll add them into a byte array.

```
byte[] myArray = {myFirstByte,mySecondByte,myThirdByte};
```

And borrow some method on how to convert byte arrays to HEX strings from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java).

```
String codeNum = bytesToHex(myArray);
```

And the result will look something like this:

```
F03DD7
```

**EDIT:**

Since you have to generate a serial number that has to be up to 6 bytes in value, I'd recommend using a `long` number.

A 6 byte number will be anywhere from 1 to 281474976710655, so you probably need to generate one randomly.

First instantiate a `Random` object which you will be able to poll numbers from:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Once you have that, poll a `long` from it for the range 1 to 281474976710655.

For this you can borrow [KennyTM's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546078/java-random-long-number-in-0-x-n-range).

So you can then generate the number like so:

```
long serialCodeNumber = nextLong(random, 281474976710655L)+1L;
```

We add the `+1L` at the end since we want it to include the last number as well as start from 1 instead of 0.

If you ever need to show a HEX string of the serialCodeNumber you can then just call:

```
String serialHex = Long.toHexString(serialCodeNumber);
```

But make sure to add any additional "0"s at the left side based on the length of the string so that it is 6-bytes = 12 characters long.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it is a 6-bytes number, like 000101F3E119. Only the second part is generated. "Serial number is a sequence 1-0xFFFFFF".
There is no value for serialCodeNumber. - I must generate...
So, here byte mySecondByte = (byte) ((serialCodeNumber / (256)) & 0xFF); instead of the serialCodeNumber, what must be here? what is the type of it, string?

Comment: `serialCodeNumber` should be something that can be divided by 256 and make sense, so I'd recommend a number, and since it's a 6-bytes number, `long` should be able to handle this. I've appended on how you could proceed with this at the end of my answer.