# Can you someone explain to me this code?

Tags: java, byte

```
int flags = 22 | 225 | 222;
```

what is this code [i don't understand what's happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVJKP.jpg)>>

Comment: What you mean by "what is this code" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Does The Bitwise & (AND) Work In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256644/how-does-the-bitwise-and-work-in-java)

Comment: "what is this code" - bizarre way of setting it to 255, if they are literal values this looks more like deliberate (but poor) obfuscation of some kind.

Comment: This bit-wise OR-ing looks **suspicious**. Maybe originally it was in **base 8**: `022 | 0225 | 0222` for Unix user/group/others rights or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
22,  in binary 0000000000010110
225, in binary 0000000011100001
222, in binary 0000000011011110
```

`|` is binary `OR` operator:

> The binary OR operation has two inputs and one output. It is like the
>   ADD operation which takes two arguments (two inputs) and produces one
>   result (one output).
>
> A     B       C
>
> 0   OR    0   ->  0
>
> 0   OR    1   ->  1
>
> 1   OR    0   ->  1
>
> 1   OR    1   ->  1

```
0000000000010110 | 0000000011100001| 0000000011011110 = 0000000011111111 (in decimal 255)
```

Answer (score -1):

| is `Bitwise Operators` so here you added 22 + 225 + 222 in binary way

Comment: | this is an bitwise OR operator it does not mean 22 + 225 + 222.

Comment: the OR operator in a binary is not '+' ? ( i think i wrote that it is 22+ 225 +222 in binary way)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the sign of OR operator ?

Comment: OR operator -> ||, binary OR operator -> |